# How do flat demand curves for stocks allow for price changes?

Tags: equities, asset-pricing

Many models in asset pricing base their assumptions on a flat demand curve for stocks, as they are viewed as goods with perfect substitutes. With this, I understand that any sort of stock sale or purchase that provides no additional information should not affect stock prices.

With a flat demand curve however, how can we explain *any* change in stock price under the assumptions of this theory? How can we graphically represent addition of new information on the original, flat demand curve?

Comment: In an efficient market, when new information arrives, *both* the demand and the supply curve shift to change the equilibrium price. It is not a suuply driven (nor a demand driven) adjustment, both the buyer and the seller redraw their curves (even if there is no trading at all).